# Wiredep Gulp Dependency Injection Not working

Tags: dependency-injection, gulp, bower, wiredep

This is my gulp task

```
gulp.task('inject', function() {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
  var options = {
    bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
    directory: './public/lib'
  };
  return gulp.src('./src/views/*.html')
  .pipe(wiredep(options))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/views'));
});
```

And these are the dependencies in my bower.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
  }
```

When I run 'gulp inject' in the command line it appears to work but my dependencies don't appear in index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce with the exact same gulp task you posted and all files were injected correctly.

I'm not seeing your index.html, but checking your task, the only thing different from mine is the bower directory. Are you sure the **./public/lib** is also set on your **bower.json** file?

Also, are you adding these tags on your html?

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

and

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

This is what my index.html looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <title>Wiredep test</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
</body>
</html>
```